# Meteor: Not able to upload image to S3 using CollectionFS

Tags: javascript, file-upload, meteor, amazon-s3

I am trying to test the upload functionality using [this](https://medium.com/@victorleungtw/how-to-upload-files-with-meteor-js-7b8e811510fa) guide with the only exception of using [cfs-s3](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/tree/master/packages/s3) package. This is very basic with simple code but I am getting an error on the client console - `Error: Access denied. No allow validators set on restricted collection for method 'insert'. [403]`

I get this error even though I have set the `allow insert` in every possible way.

Here is my client code:

```
// client/images.js
var imageStore = new FS.Store.S3("images");

Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
    stores: [imageStore],
    filter: {
        allow: {
            contentTypes: ['image/*']
        }
    }
});

Images.deny({
 insert: function(){
 return false;
 },
 update: function(){
 return false;
 },
 remove: function(){
 return false;
 },
 download: function(){
 return false;
 }
 });

Images.allow({
 insert: function(){
 return true;
 },
 update: function(){
 return true;
 },
 remove: function(){
 return true;
 },
 download: function(){
 return true;
 }
});
```

And there is a simple file input button on the homepage -

```
// client/home.js
'change .myFileInput': function(e, t) {
    FS.Utility.eachFile(e, function(file) {
        Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
          if (err){
             console.log(err)  // --- THIS is the error
          } else {
             // handle success depending what you need to do

            console.log("fileObj id: " + fileObj._id)
            //Meteor.users.update(userId, {$set: imagesURL});
          }
        });
     });
}
```

I have set the proper policies and everything on S3 but I don't think this error is related to S3 at all.

```
// server/images.js
var imageStore = new FS.Store.S3("images", {
    accessKeyId: "xxxx",
    secretAccessKey: "xxxx",
    bucket: "www.mybucket.com"
});

Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
    stores: [imageStore],
    filter: {
        allow: {
            contentTypes: ['image/*']
        }
    }
});
```

I have also published and subscribed to the collections appropriately. I have been digging around for hours but can't seem to figure out what is happening.

**EDIT:** I just readded `insecure` package and everything now works. So basically, the problem is with allow/deny rules but I am actually doing it. I am not sure why it is not acknowledging the rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the FS.Collection's [allow/deny](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow) rules in sever-only code. These are server-side rules applied to the underlying Mongo.Collection that FS.Collection creates.

The best approach is to export the AWS keys as the following environment variables: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, remove the accessKeyId and secretAccessKey options from the FS.Store, and then move the FS.Collection constructor calls to run on both the client and server. The convenience of using env vars is mentioned on the [cfs:s3](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/tree/master/packages/s3) page

In addition to this you can control the bucket name using [Meteor.settings.public](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_settings), which is handy when you want to use different buckets based on the environment.

Comment: Please also see the wiki page on [Security](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/wiki/Security) for more details on the CollectionFS Security config